# Заблокировали домен за то что нет доступа к почтовому ящику. Как его разблокировать?

Tags: домен

Всем привет.

Четыре года назад зарегистрировал домен на webnames.ru Поскольку изначально делал сайт ради сайта, то по приколу при регистрации указал свой псевдоним блогера. То есть не настоящее имя. К тому же почтовым ящиком, который указывал при регистрации, уже давно не пользовался. Соответственно потерял к нему доступ.

И вот webnames блокирует мой домен.
Я им пишу за, что?
Они. За то, что Ваш почтовый ящик не отвечает. 
Цитирую:

> Нами была произведена ручная, которая показала, что контактные данные
>   администратора домена (в частности, email) не действительны.

- Я им говорю, что готов предоставить свои настоящие данные и подтвердить их сканом паспорта.
- Они. Нам нужен скан "Васи Пупкина".

Что делать? Куда обратится? Кто сталкиваля с такой ситуацией?

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант: если домен продлялся давненько, предлагаю подождать пока домен освободится и переоформить по новой, на свои правильные данные. В противном случае, видимо, только восстанавливать доступ к тому e-mail, но это тоже может окончится неудачей в связи с неподлинными данными.

Answer (score 0):

По своему опыту скажу, что скорее всего у Вас ничего не получится. У меня была проблема с двумя доменами. По первому не решил, по второму решил путем приезда в офис регистратора и с изложением всей ситуации. Можете так же попробовать, но шансов мало.

Comment: Печально. Но ехать в Самару у меня нет возможности.